# Inserting some javascript code with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a way to insert some javascript code in the page which works with all browsers but not with IE. Here is a sample:
http://boxfly.free.fr/tmp/innerjs.html

The line which does not work properly with IE is:

```
ele.text = document.getElementById('DIV_js').innerHTML ;
```

If I change this line to:

```
ele.text = 'alert("Hello")' ;
```

It works. But I need to be able to insert code which is on a lot of lines, not only one line for displaying an alert, that's why I am using a DIV to contain the Javascript code... ;)

Does anyone know how to make this script work with IE:

```
<body>

<div id="DIV_js" style="display:none;">
var i = 'here' ;
function hello() {
  alert('toto says '  + i) ;
}
</div>
<script>

var ele = document.createElement("script") ;
ele.type = 'text/javascript' ;
ele.text = document.getElementById('DIV_js').innerHTML ;

document.body.insertBefore(ele, (document.getElementsByTagName("div"))[0]);

</script>

<span onClick="hello();">Click to display alert</span>

</body>
```

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243756/innerhtml-not-working-properly-in-internet-explorer

Comment: i think, the better way is add the script in runtime, but to the head, like google or facebook does: (function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');                        ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

Comment: Is it not working on IE6 or is it not working for you in IE7 and IE8 too? That example (in the link http://boxfly.free.fr/tmp/innerjs.html) worked for me in IE7 and IE8 on Win XP.

Comment: @Manjula Yes, now it's working on IE7 to 9. I have uploaded the script if someone looks a help for the same issue. I don't test IE6 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/nGxTf/

I changed it to an eval() call, rather than inserting it into a script element.

Comment: So - does that mean this answer works for you?  If so - care to mark it so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// The rest of the code above omitted for brievity
var ele = document.createElement("script");
ele.type = 'text/javascript';
ele.innerHTML = document.getElementById('DIV_js').innerHTML;

// Don't use getElementsByTagName, you risk inserting the script in more than one div
document.getElementById('yourDiv').appendChild(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML works form IE6 to IE9 but it has buggy.innerHTML on tbody elements is readOnly in IE

Comment: It's ok, thanks to Jake it's now working with IE. 

I have uploaded the file, might be usefull for someone who wants to add to Javascript code to the page which is in a DIV:
http://boxfly.free.fr/tmp/innerjs.html

And with 

    eval(ele.text);

we don't need anymore to use document.body.insertBefore(...) :)