# Javascript - Passing a script to innerHTML on older browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to pass a script into an iframe dynamically so it will run there (`content` in the example comes from the server) using this snippet:

```
content = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<a   href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">bla</a>"");</script>';
el = document.getElementById('iframeName');
iframeDoc = el.contentWindow.document;

tempEl = iframeDoc.createElement('div');
tempEl.innerHTML = content;
```

It runs great on new browsers but when I try to run it on IE8 and lower, the innerHTML comes up null.
I tried different approaches but the inner HTML is the only option i can think of that can run the script i'm passing in to tempEl. Any ideas on how to pass `content` into `tempEl.innerHTML` so it will run the script and also work on IE8-?

Comment: Judging by the syntax highlighting, I'd love to know how this "runs great on new browsers"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HTML content into an iframe in IE8, IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504816/how-to-set-html-content-into-an-iframe-in-ie8-ie9)

Comment: Do you know if your iframeDoc reference is valid?  Also, maybe try:    iframeDoc.body.createElement('div');

Comment: I think I got it, I went by the question @Vucko pointed out and took off `tempEl` and added `iframeDoc.write(content);`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol noted, fixed syntax.

Comment: @richb01 the iframeDoc reference is valid and I tried iframeDoc.body.createElement('div') , it didn't help.

Comment: [SO: .InnerHTML Not working properly in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243756/innerhtml-not-working-properly-in-internet-explorer)..? An answer to this question states that scripts must be written to the `<head>` of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is:

```
el = document.getElementById('iframeName');
iframeDoc = el.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.write(content);
```

it's a lot shorter and is cross-browser (instead of using innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried injecting the script element into the head of the document?

I am not to sure about `script` tags, but you must inject `link` and `style` elements into the head of a document for it to be interpreted correctly by older IE browsers.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.rel = 'JavaScript';
script.innerHTML = 'document.write("<a href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\">bla</a>");';

var el = document.getElementById('iframeName');
iframeDoc = el.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: When I try this the script is added to the head of the document but it does not run.